# group objects in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm not sure how to explain this clearly, but I have a JSON result from an API that returns an unknown number of products with separate entries for each product and its price on 3 different services.

I then need to take those groups and iterate through them processing them as a group.

For example dataset.

```
[
  { 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'ebay' }
  { 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'amazon' }
  { 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'newegg' }
  { 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'newegg' }
  { 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'newegg' }
  { 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'ebay' }
  { 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'amazon' }
  { 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'amazon' }
  { 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'ebay' }
]
```

There are two API result sets, the first gives you a list of the available products and with a unique entry paired with the service (Amazon, eBay, Newegg).  So for each product, there are 3 entries, but they won't be in order.

The second API returns the product-service & price.
Example price result would be.

```
[
    ProductC-NewEgg: Price
    ProdutA-NewEgg: Price
    ProductB-NewEgg: Price
    ProductA-Amazon: Price
    ProductA-Ebay: Price
    ProductC-Amazon: Price
    ProductB-Ebay: Price
    ProductC-Ebay: Price
    ProductB-Amazon: Price
]
```

My initial thought was to get a unique list of all the products from the first API and put them in a list.  Then go through each combination of product/service and fill in a dictionary stored under each product list element.

So the result would be something like>

```
[
Product A { price a, b c }
Product B { price a, b c }
Product C { price a, b c }
]
```

I feel like I am approaching it wrong.

Comment: Your dataset contains no prices. Please add enough sample input data so we can understand how it is related to the expected result date.

Comment: What is it you are trying to *accomplish*? To group the prices together? What use is the first result, from what you are describing, it sounds redundant.

Comment: You should try to create *actual example data*

Comment: I would need to get all the prices for each product then iterate through each product and compare them and display some data on how they related to (i.e. 5% higher, 1% Lower) than a baseline.

Comment: SO isn't here to write code for you. Even if it was, your examples aren't valid syntax so it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Not looking for code, just what approach I should go.  The examples are all just list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your requirements clear. But check this out:

```
>>> first_api_result = [
  { 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'ebay' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'amazon' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'newegg' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'newegg' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'newegg' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgeta', 'type': 'ebay' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'amazon' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgetb', 'type': 'amazon' }
  ,{ 'name': 'widgetc', 'type': 'ebay' }
]
>>> second_api_result=[
    {'widgeta-NewEgg': 10 }
    ,{'widgetb-NewEgg': 20  }
    ,{'widgetc-NewEgg': 30 }
    ,{'widgetb-Amazon': 35 }
    ,{'widgetb-Ebay': 40   }
    ,{'widgeta-Amazon': 50 }
    ,{'widgetc-Ebay': 60   }
    ,{'widgeta-Ebay': 70   }
    ,{'widgetc-Amazon': 80 }
]
>>> result = {d['name']:[]for d in first_api_result}
>>> for price_dict in second_api_result:
        product,price = price_dict.items()[0]
        result[product[:product.index('-')]].append(price)


>>> result
{'widgetc': [30, 60, 80], 'widgetb': [20, 35, 40], 'widgeta': [10, 50, 70]}
```

Comment: This is basically the direction I was going, I used dictionary with dictionaries for the three prices so I can later add more and I can refer to them by name.

Seems very hacky to me, and my python experience is splotchy so I wasn't sure if I was missing out on some awesome feature that makes this easier.